# Passing AD authentication credentials to IE browser in C# Windows Form

Tags: winforms

I have a Sharepoint site and I want to open this site in IE by using C# Windows Application. I successfully open the site in IE but my question is how do I send the UserCredentials to the site. It opens the site in IE with defalut credentials.
My defalut credentials are username: systemaccount password=123
but i want to open Sharepoint site in IE with some different credentials like username: abc password: 123 (I have "abc" as a AD and Sharepoint User)

here is my code for opening Sharepoint site in IE

```
SecureString sec = new SecureString();
             sec.AppendChar('1');
             sec.AppendChar('2');
             sec.AppendChar('3');

Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", url,"abc",sec,"moss.local");
```

here is my Sharepoint site URL.......
abc is my username by which i want to login
sec is a password SecureString password
moss.local is my domain where "abc" AD user exists.....

Comment: Hi, Have you found any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it seems to be working for me and "user" gets to access the site, not the logged in one:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "http://server/sites/spsite/page.aspx");
startInfo.UserName = @"user";
SecureString p = new SecureString();
p.AppendChar('p');
p.AppendChar('w');
p.AppendChar('d');
startInfo.Password = p;
startInfo.Domain = "mydomain";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: I am getting the error below when i try to use it:"The directory name is invalid". Any Idea?